# Excel, Creating 3 conditions for Conditional Formating

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My situation is this.  I have an excel sheet that contains 6 columns I need to compare G:L,

in these  columns each cell contains a Dollar value or are Blank.
I need to figure out how I can return into column M 3 distinct values

- ALL cells within a row Match
- The row Contains Blanks
- NOT all rows Match

I used =NOT(STDEV(G3:L3))
which gave me True / False / #DIV/0!  but when I tried conditional formatting with 3 Rules

```
Formula:=$M4:$M2693=TRUE (background GREEN) Applies to =$A$4:$L$2693
Formula:=$M4:$M2693=FALSE (background RED) Applies to =$A$4:$L$2693
Formula:=$M4:$M2693=#DIV/0! (background YELLOW) Applies to =$A$4:$L$2693
```

I would get no Yellow rows,  DIV/0 Rows would be the colour of what ever row was above them.

I figure if I can have column M  return 3 distinct values be they A, B C 1,2,3 or anything that isn't #DIV/0!  I should be able to make conditional formatting work

BONUS is if I can have it return 4 values the 4th value indicating ALL rows are Blank,  since that would be heading rows but it doesn't really matter as I can manual edit those 40ish rows.

*** EDIT ***
Tom Lead me in the right direction,  but to get the formatting perfectly I did have to make a few modifications

```
    =COUNTBLANK($H$3:$L$3)=5 (No Formatting) 
    =STDEV($H3:$L3)>0 (Red)
    =STDEV($H3:$L3)=0  (Green)
    =COUNTBLANK($H3:$L3)<5 (Yellow)
```

Then it worked fantastically,  So if you're reading this because you have the same problem tweeking the order can have a lot to do with your conditional formatting

Comment: Do you want to know if a row contains _some_ blanks? What if it only contains one number and all the rest are blanks?

Comment: Or (say) three numbers all the same and three blanks?

Comment: @TomSharpe Sorry for the delay,   A row can consist of - 5 dollar values, or 5 blanks and everything in between.   So what I want is IF the row contains ANY blanks it is yellow,  if it contains no blanks it is either red or green.   basically any row that has 1 number and any blanks be it 1 or be it 4 that row has to have a meeting generated about it.  that is different from the Red row meeting,  the green rows need no meeting

Comment: OK fine, I'll have a look at it. Using STDEV seems a good idea, just needs tweaking a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have four rules to be fired in this order:-

```
=COUNT($G4:$L4)=0      -  no format set

=COUNT($G4:$L4)<6      -  yellow

=STDEV($G4:$L4)>0      -  red

=STDEV($G4:$L4)=0      -  green
```

After entering them in Conditional Formatting I used Manage Rules, setting the rules in this order and ticking the stop on error box so they behaved properly.

It's true that STDEV will give a #DIV/0! error if it has less than two numbers to work on, but that doesn't matter because it will be covered by the 'yellow' case and even if it wasn't it would just mean that it wouldn't fire.

A formula to give values for a helper column would look like this:-

```
=IF(COUNT($G4:$L4)=0,1,(IF(COUNT($G4:$L4)<6,2,(IF(STDEV($G4:$L4)>0,3,4)))))
```

Comment: So these are rules to be applied in conditional formatting?   right now I have my =NOT(STDEV(G4:L4)) in $M4 as a helper column then I apply my conditional formatting based on the M4 result,   Are you saying I should use your formula's IN the conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes that was what I was suggesting. But you could certainly use a helper column if you wanted to, maybe to give four different values and then use them in the conditional format.

Comment: OK there a couple of things we could try. One is it might help if I put the equivalent formula for the helper column and you could see if it works, the other if you could show a few rows of what your data looks like.

Comment: Thank you!  works now.  And now I'm sad because I see WAY more red than I expected  so many meetings.  ....

Comment: As an FYI I've tweeked the help you gave me to finally be perfect.    I had to list them in this Order  'code' =COUNTBLANK($H$3:$L$3)=5 (No Formatting)  // =STDEV($H3:$L3)>0 (Red) // =STDEV($H3:$L3)=0 // =COUNTBLANK($H3:$L3)<5  'code'  ---  When doing it the way you listed I never could get the No Formatting to work perfectly  but now it does.   Thank you so much giving me the direction I needed